# How do I add text to an empty element in Hpricot?

Tags: ruby, hpricot

If I have an empty tag:

```
<tag/>
```

How can I add text so that I end up with:

```
<tag>Hello World!</tag>
```

I can only seem to swap the whole tag with different content or add content before/after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I just needed to use the call:

```
my_node.inner_html my_content
```